# How to find matched php.ini file correctly

Tags: php

The machine had install PHP5.6 originally.I install PHP 7.2 from source.

```
# PHP5.6 dir
/xxx/php/56/

# PHP7.2 dir
/xxx/php/72/
```

PHP 7.2 cannot find itself `php.ini` file, even though I put the `php.ini` fie in `/xxx/php/72/etc`

```
# PHP7.2
$ PHP -v 
Failed loading /xxx/php/56/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/opcache.so:  /xxx/php/56/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/opcache.so: undefined symbol: zend_opcode_handlers
Failed loading /usr/local/zend/php56/ZendGuardLoader.so:  /usr/local/zend/php56/ZendGuardLoader.so: undefined symbol: zval_used_for_init
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/xxx/php/56/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/arms.so' (tried: /xxx/php/56/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/arms.so (/xxx/php/56/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/arms.so: undefined symbol: zval_used_for_init), /xxx/php/56/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718//xxx/php/56/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/arms.so.so (/xxx/php/56/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718//xxx/php/56/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/arms.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP 7.2.28 (cli) (built: Feb 26 2020 23:59:23) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
```

And

```
# PHP7.2
$ php -i | grep ini
Failed loading...
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /xxx/php/72/etc
Loaded Configuration File => /xxx/php/56/etc/php.ini
```

And

```
# PHP7.2
$ php -ini | grep ini
Failed loading...
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /xxx/php/56/etc
Loaded Configuration File:         /xxx/php/56/etc/php.ini
```

Environments:

- CentOS Linux release 7.7.1908 (Core)
- Nginx
- there is a php-fpm(php5.6) service running

Is there a cache or some config?I had search  Windows have the environment PHPRC, what about CentOS ?

And `php -i` vs `php --ini` output is different.

Comment: Recompile with a proper `configure  --with-config-file-path=/etc/php/7.2/` etc. /lib/local lookups are impossible to debug.

Comment: @mario I had compiled with `configure --prefix=/xxx/php/72 --with-config-file-path=/xxx/php/72/etc' ...` . Do you mean the path must be `/etc/php/7.2` ?

Comment: @mario Thanks for your comment, remind me. I find the error.I compile the source with wrong param `./configure ----prefix=/xxx/php/56 --with-config-file-path=/xxx/php/56/etc` at first, after that I recompile `./configure ----prefix=/xxx/php/72 --with-config-file-path=/xxx/php/72/etc` but not run `make clean`.I just run the right steps again, the error disappear.